# Unknown Address Format Parsing Bitcoin Addresses from Blockchair Data

Tags: address, address-generation

I've obtained a list of all current Bitcoin addresses with balances from Blockchair, which is downloadable from their data repository located [here](https://blockchair.com/dumps).  I have downloaded the `Bitcoin / Addresses` TSV database dump.

The list consists of:

- ~23m P2PKH (`1xxx`) addresses
- ~5.8m P2SH (`3xxx`) addresses
- ~1.3m Bech32 (`bc1xxx`) addresses

However, there are also ~400k addresses that have prefixes that I don't recognise, including:

- d-xxx (example: `d-b697921d996831d1a26ca8d8e92571c1`)
- m-xxx (example: `m-942943e227462513f33c4f32ec6f1e56`)
- s-xxx (example: `s-2ad548f2459c0ed6123400e5d61a479e`)

**Are these valid Bitcoin addresses?**

If they are, how do I view information about them?

If they are not, any idea why they appear in the dump of current Bitcoin addresses from Blockchair?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Having investigated this following @MCCCS's [answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/96780/106912), the following is information about the addresses provided by Blockchair support in response to the [issue I raised in their GitHub](https://github.com/Blockchair/Blockchair.Support/issues/273):

> In fact, there are no addresses on the Bitcoin blockchain. There are
> only scripts, some of them are standard and can be converted to a
> Bitcoin address, some of them can’t — like nulldata (OP_RETURN)
> outputs, nonstandard, and bare multisig. We use the d- prefix for
> nulldata, m- for bare multisig, and s- for everything else.
>
> This is briefly mentioned in this API documentation section:
> https://blockchair.com/api/docs#link_300

Therefore, these *addresses* (for want of a better word) are valid transactions on the Bitcoin blockchain.

The prefixes used are:

- `d-` nulldata
- `m-` bare multisig
- `s-` everything else

In conclusion, the **data is valid** but the outputs are not addresses in the normal sense of the word.

Answer (score 2):

Those are invalid addresses that don't belong to any cryptocurrency. You should file a bug report at https://github.com/Blockchair/Blockchair.Support/issues since those might even be their database secrets.

Those are of 16 bytes. My initial guess about their format would be SHA-1, but Bitcoin does not use SHA-1. Probably it's related to their database.

For example on this page https://blockchair.com/dogecoin/address/942943e227462513f33c4f32ec6f1e56 it seems Blockchair thinks `942943e227462513f33c4f32ec6f1e56` is a valid Doge address. It's not.

To prevent this from happening again in the future, they could implement input sanitization before INSERT statements

Comment: Thank you. I've raised an issue on their support forum: https://github.com/Blockchair/Blockchair.Support/issues/273

Comment: I've received a response from Blockchair support and provided the outcome in a separate answer. Thank you again for your input, which ultimately led to me finding the answer!