# How is the d-30ad... pseudo-address generated for OP_RETURN

Tags: address-generation, op-return

How are the pseudo-addresses (e.g., "d-30ad...") used in Bitcoin's OP_RETURN transactions generated? Specifically what process or criteria are used to create these unique identifiers following the "d-" prefix? [Here's](https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/8bae12b5f4c088d940733dcd1455efc6a3a69cf9340e17a981286d3778615684) an example transaction with one of these addresses, however I've noticed that they are not unique to Blockchair

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/Blockchair/Blockchair.Support/issues/273) answer your question? Where other than blockchair have you seen this? I'm leaning towards this being generated randomly by some hash function that is not related to the transaction asm (such as any data after the OP_RETURN), or some combination of the txid + vout, but you will have to ask blockchair about this as it is definitely unique to their platform as far as I can tell. More importantly why would you want to know this, what does it solve?

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/96779/unknown-address-format-parsing-bitcoin-addresses-from-blockchair-data)